# Unable to limit CPU speed on Ubuntu 22.04 with cpufrequtils

Tags: 22.04, performance, cpu, cpufreq, frequency

Based on this: [How can I easily control CPU speed on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635426/how-can-i-easily-control-cpu-speed-on-ubuntu) I try to manually force some of my CPU cores on Ubuntu 22.04.1 `5.15.0-56-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux` to be limited to 800 MHz using `cpufreq` (from: cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009) but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; do sudo cpufreq-set -c $i -d 800 MHz; done

$ watch -n2 'cpufreq-info | grep "current CPU freq"'

Every 2.0s: cpufreq-info | grep "current CPU freq"                                                                                                          
  current CPU frequency is 3.45 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 1.44 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 1.85 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 1.61 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 2.58 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 1.97 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 1.26 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 3.45 GHz.
```

Why doesn't it work and how to make it work?

Here's the `/proc/cpuinfo` on one core:

```
processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 140
model name  : 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xa4
cpu MHz     : 2570.099
cache size  : 12288 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 27
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l2 invpcid_single cdp_l2 ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req avx512vbmi umip pku ospke avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg avx512_vpopcntdq rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm avx512_vp2intersect md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
vmx flags   : vnmi preemption_timer posted_intr invvpid ept_x_only ept_ad ept_1gb flexpriority apicv tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest vapic_reg vid ple pml ept_mode_based_exec tsc_scaling
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs eibrs_pbrsb
bogomips    : 5606.40
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

and:

```
$ sudo lshw -class cpu
  *-cpu                     
       description: CPU
       product: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 10
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: 6.140.1
       serial: None
       slot: U3E1
       size: 3542MHz
       capacity: 4700MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 100MHz
       capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l2 invpcid_single cdp_l2 ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req avx512vbmi umip pku ospke avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg avx512_vpopcntdq rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm avx512_vp2intersect md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities cpufreq
       configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 microcode=164 threads=8
```

Computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad P15s.

#### EDIT

As suggested by Doug Smythies in the comment below, here are some more command outputs:

```sh
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
```

```sh
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
```

```sh
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/affected_cpus:6
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/base_frequency:1200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/energy_performance_available_preferences:default performance balance_performance balance_power power 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference:balance_performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/related_cpus:6
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:1006285
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4700000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed:<unsupported>
```

```sh
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/hwp_dynamic_boost:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:8
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates:44
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct:44
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding the CPU frequency scaling driver and governor information. `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. And all the information for 1 CPU: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/*` and, if you are using the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think my answer, done after my comment, is correct. You can confirm by doing the same as I did in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Intel processors, at least up to 10th Gen, the issue is that there is only one CPU clock frequency PLL (Phase Locked Loop). Inputs (requests for a frequency) to the PLL come from all the CPUs in addition to some internal contributors. In the case where HWP (Hardware Pstate Control) is enabled, the CPU inputs are merely guidelines and the processor decides. A CPUs vote is dis-guarded if it is in a deep enough idle state. The CPU frequency output from the PLL is presented to all the CPUs. Since you have not set all CPU to a maximum frequency of 800 MHz, it appears the remaining one is asking for a higher frequency. There are frequencies other than 3.45 GHz listed for other CPU because they are sometimes idle and sometimes not, resulting in a different number over the same time.

Example using a i5-10600K, 6 cores, 12 CPUs:

First, set all CPUs except 0, to a max frequency of 800 MHz and check it:

```
doug@s19:~$ for i in `seq 1 11`; do echo 800000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq; done
800000
800000
800000
800000
800000
800000
800000
800000
800000
800000
800000
doug@s19:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:800000
```

Now, look at CPU frequencies:

```
doug@s19:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:799994
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800458
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:799748
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800173
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800003
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800063
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
```

The system is idle so nothing is driving up the CPU 0 desire for higher frequency, so the clock is low. The 4.1 GHz numbers are misleading, and actually indicate stale data due to the CPU being in deep idle for a long time (this output is a function of kernel version, and other users might get different).

Now load down CPU 0 and check again:

```
doug@s19:~$ taskset -c 0 yes > /dev/null &
[1] 3911
doug@s19:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4799997
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4800121
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
doug@s19:~$ fg
taskset -c 0 yes > /dev/null
^C
doug@s19:~$
```

Now, if I set all CPUs to have a maximum frequency of 800 MHz, then it will work:

```
doug@s19:~$ echo 800000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
800000
doug@s19:~$ taskset -c 0 yes > /dev/null &
[1] 3920
doug@s19:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:799997
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800322
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800101
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800105
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:800001
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:4100000
doug@s19:~$ fg
taskset -c 0 yes > /dev/null
^C
doug@s19:~$
```

Disclaimer: There might be some inaccuracies in this answer. I am not certain that this 11th gen processor only has one PLL (Phase Locked Loop).

**EDIT:** To revert the changes, just reverse what was done. If the original maximum CPU frequency setting has been forgotten, then inquire first:

```
doug@s19:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4800000
```

Set it back, and check it:

```
doug@s19:~$ echo 4800000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
4800000
doug@s19:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:4800000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you be willing to add to your post a way to reset the default values after such modifications?

Comment: I have intel i5, with 12 threads, even with this  the clock doesn't stay at 800MHz, on all CPU's after you  exit the task set. It stays 800MHz as long as the task is running. when you quit the task it reverts some of the cores to 2.7GHz

Comment: @abacusreader : What you are seeing is likely stale frequencies being listed for idle cores. It depends on the kernel version and CPU frequency scaling driver and governor. See the bugzilla [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217597).

Comment: Thank you for replying and trying to help. I am trying to optimise some java code. I am using System.nanotime to get the time elapsed.  I want to benchmark the code by setting the CPU to 800MHz but as I said, code takes about 1.5ms when the CPU clock is left at 2.7GHz . When it goes to 800MHz  the code takes about 3ms however when I rerun the java code it goes back to 1.5ms. That is when I noticed that the CPU is going back to 2.7Ghz. Is there a way that I can run my Java code assigned to a particular CPU core other than by getting the PID and using taskset?

Comment: @abacusreader : So, some other program is changing the settings allowing higher CPU frequencies again. I only know of `taskset -c 5 ./myprogram` to force `myprogram` to run on CPU 5.

Comment: thanks for the taskset tip, I will play with it

Comment: @abacusreader : By the way, when I am benchmarking code I'll time it running say 10,000 times instead of just once. i.e. for 15 to 30 seconds for your example.

Comment: Yes that is what I too do in the loop inside the code, if I run it once it gives me 10x slower result

Comment: @DougSmythies The grep shows correct values only if the CPU is loaded and only for a brief period after the program has exited. I did the following test, ran a code on CPU 9 by setting it at 800MHz and then ran on CPU 11 by setting it at 1GHz - Measured the time to nano seconds. CPU 9 was slower than CPU 11, grep of  scaling_cpu_freq showed correct CPU clock. however after few minutes when I do grep it shows clock at 2.7GHz for both CPU 9 and 11. but when I run the code again, I get same performance as that of 800MHz and 1GHz respectively

Comment: @abacusreader : Please read [my answer to another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482295/cpufreq-set-not-taking-effect-on-fixing-cpu-frequency-on-ubuntu-20/1482667#1482667). If you haven't set the CPU frequency limit for all CPU's, then another CPU might asking for 2.7 GHz and getting it for all.