# How to change maximum allowable CPU frequency?

Tags: cpu, overheating

I want to permanently change the maximum allowable CPU frequency as some code changed it so I am constantly overheating my CPU. Can someone help me out with this problem? My changes to the new maximum frequency don't take action as I'm still constantly hitting 2500 MHz, which is the maximum of my CPU.

[image]

[image]

Comment: More info about your CPU is needed, otherwise your question could be a duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446918/unable-to-limit-cpu-speed-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-cpufrequtils

Comment: @Nmath: My guess is that he want to limit it (downwards...)

Comment: The wording is a bit ambiguous. OP can you help us out? My understanding of your question is essentially "I want to change the max frequency so I can overheat my CPU". If you're actually trying to solve an overheating problem, reducing the CPU frequency is not going to address the actual cause of the overheating. If your CPU is overheating, then there is a problem with the cooling system. Usually this is dust and/or thermal compound that has dried out and needs to be replaced. These are fairly easy repairs that most people can do themselves following a guide.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the cooling system as I didnt had this issue before. I used something called auto-cpufreq to make the adjustments for me. At the moment I am constantly hitting 93 degrees since this.

Comment: Overheating 100% has everything to do with the cooling system. A cooling system is dysfunctional if it can't keep hardware at a safe temperature when all components are running at 100% resources indefinitely. If the issue is dust or dried thermal paste, the problem is just going to get worse and worse if you ignore it. Saying you didn't have the problem before is not evidence to support your belief, but it's consistent with dust, etc.  While you can certainly keep limiting the CPU frequency lower and lower and lower, you're only addressing the symptom and doing nothing to address the cause.

Comment: I agree with @Luuk that we need to know your processor make and model. But I also agree that the link Luuk provided should work for you. Your processor does get pretty warm given that it is spending so much time in a deep idle state (i.e. C7), so I also agree that something seems not right with your cooling.